# Хочу внести документ в таблицу базы данных, в неё вносится id таблицы, id пользователя которое берётся из другой таблицы и сам документ

Tags: php, mysql

Вот код, в папку он файл заносит, а в базу нет. В чём может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: код надо приводить в тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно делаете запрос в базу данных.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php
Вы пытаетесь занести СТРОКУ запроса на ID пользователя, не выполняя его) просто заносите как текст. + не потятно, где вы получили переменную $document

Comment: А как можно преобразовывать ID из базы в текст и потом его туда вносить?

Comment: 100 лет не работал с mysqli.. она морально устарела)
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='login'");
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { print_r($res) }

Comment: Спасибо большое)